# Open and close connection to db or keep it

Tags: php, database

I have seen a lot of answers regarding `.NET` and `C#` applications, but I didn't find what I was looking for about Web ones (or else I didn't search well and I apologize for it).

My question is about connections to database during queries : Should I open and close a connection each query I am doing or should I create one and keep it all long ?
I guess it's the first one, but I want some informations about the differences between both regarding **Performance** and **Security**.

Moreover, is this enough to close a connection :

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foo', '', '')
// queries
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.  That's not to say you shouldn't do it manually. By doing it manually you could open  new one to a different db or server. Personally I believe closing them once you dont need them would improve the performace as PDO query has then closed and stopped performing tasks, this would possibly only reduce the time by 1-3ms but thats alot when you need it.

Comment: PHP will automatically close a connection, even if I use a `global $dbh` before each query ?

Comment: Not globally defined, Think the PDO object as a persistent connection it will not automatically close the connection if globably defined and PHP will store that global and keep it running in the background.

Comment: Then I must close it afterwards, right ?

Comment: Maybe it would, I'll test it out and i'll get back to you.

Comment: You must, nor should you close connections manually if there isn't a specific need for that behaviour. You should also never use global variables to store resources such as database connections - it has the same effect as looking into a barrel of a loaded gun - it's stupid and you can shoot your face.

Comment: @JamieSterling - closing a connection would yield no performance. How does that make any sense? Closing it would add overhead since now your program must do more work. How is more work = performance exactly?

Comment: @N.B. And how would keeping it active perform better? Rather than killing the current active state that would be constantly running a background process you would rather keep it going?

Comment: @JamieSterling - you do realize that if you don't query the db, that this imaginary process you have in mind does nothing? Have you ever heard of word "idle"? What you wrote makes no sense, is backed up with 0 facts and is something that you *think* is true. We can argue but that will lead nowhere - you are simply wrong in your assumption. Not closing = more performance. Easy as that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You should **not** close the connection if you want **performance**. You will have 0 effect on security by closing connection manually. Closing the connection will make things slower.

I'm going to write the rest of the answer based on your criteria of performance and I will assume you are serving php via `php-fpm` (if not, you should).

Closing and opening a connection carries overhead of handshaking with MySQL and opening file descriptors. If you have a lot of requests going on, this process will impact performance for no gain. 
Using a **persistent** connection however, will boost the performance.

Here's why: once php script ends, php will keep the connection open. The next request coming in will use already established connection - you avoid the handshake, tcp overhead and what not.

Excerpt from php manual:

> Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections
>   to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end
>   of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests
>   a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection
>   cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new
>   connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting
>   in a faster web application.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) -> scroll down to example 4 to see how to implement this.